# Publishing Prerecorded Lidar-PCAP file and IMU-Measurments as ros-bag

Tags: gps, ros, point-clouds, imu, rosbag

I have a prerecorded lidar point-clouds as pcap-file and also IMU and GPS records. All sensors were synchronized over gps-time. I would like to publish them as ROS-messages in real-time, which means I should read each point-cloud frame and imu-measurement at their own sample rates (IMU=125HZ, Lidar=10HZ) and publish them as ros-messages.

I would like to know if it is possible, and what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [this-post](https://answers.ros.org/question/213080/convert-raw-velodyne-vlp16-pcap-to-bagfile/)?

Comment: So, each message should have an [`std_msgs/Header`](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) element, containing the time it was published at. As long as your data has these timestamps, [`rosbag play`](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play) will publish them at those relative offsets. If you only have 10 lidar msgs a second, each 100 ms apart, you should observe that. If this is not the case, please update the post.